kdb/q How do I split a column into two by the first 6 characters?
My table has a column like this:



DateName




2024.01.01Ann


2024.01.02Bob


2024.01.03Ant



I want to be able to split this column into two, where the first one is the Date from DateName and the second is the Name from DateName:



Date
Name




2024.01.01
Ann


2024.01.02
Bob


2024.01.03
Ant



I know that I can cut using '10_DateName but I don't know how to split the first part and create a Date column from that and a Name column from the rest of the field. Looking for opinions on how I can approach, otherwise I was thinking of doing a 'first 10 characters' and 'rest' approach and adding new columns for each.

Sample table:
q)t:([] DateName:("2024.01.01Ann";"2024.01.02Bob";"2024.01.03Ant"))

q)t
DateName
---------------
"2024.01.01Ann"
"2024.01.02Bob"
"2024.01.03Ant"

Example using @ for apply and composition:

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#apply-at-index-at
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#composition

And \:/: each-left each-right iterators

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right

q)flip exec `Date`Name!flip("D"$#[10] @;`$_[10] @)@\:/:DateName from t
Date       Name
---------------
2024.01.01 Ann
2024.01.02 Bob
2024.01.03 Ant

Or with composition removed:
q)flip exec `Date`Name!"DS"$flip(#[10];_[10])@\:/:DateName from t
Date       Name
---------------
2024.01.01 Ann
2024.01.02 Bob
2024.01.03 Ant

And simplified to only need 10 entered once:
q)flip exec `Date`Name!"DS"$flip((#;_)@\:10)@\:/:DateName from t
Date       Name
---------------
2024.01.01 Ann
2024.01.02 Bob
2024.01.03 Ant


In terms of a basic select statement you could do:
q)select Date:"D"$10#'DateName,Name:`$10_'DateName from t
Date       Name
------------------
2024.01.01 Anna
2024.01.02 Bob
2024.01.03 Anthony

but you would really make your life easier if you forced the upstream source to not append dates and names together. At the very least have delimiters put between them, then it becomes as simple as (similar to rian's answer):
q)t:([] DateName:("2024.01.01|Ann";"2024.01.02|Bob";"2024.01.03|Ant"));
q)exec flip`Date`Name!("DS";"|")0:DateName from t
Date       Name
---------------
2024.01.01 Ann
2024.01.02 Bob
2024.01.03 Ant

